Physical interpretation and validity of QHO hamiltonian term: $\hat{a}\hat{n} + \hat{n}\hat{a}^{\dagger}$
For a quantum harmonic oscillator can we have a Hamiltonian term of the following form, and what would be its physical interpretation:
$$\hat{a}\hat{n} + \hat{n}\hat{a}^{\dagger}$$

In such a Hamiltonian, the number of particles is not conserved, i.e., it changes throughout the time evolution. Unless you add some new types of interactions (e.g. exchange of particles with the environment), these terms will not appear in a quantum harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian, which generically preserves the particle number in the system

By $n$ do you mean $n=a^\dagger a$?

Yes, sorry for not mentioning, n is the number operator and a is the annihilation operator.

Let me first point out that a Hamiltonian with such a term is obviously not a harmonic oscillator ($H_{HO}=\hbar\omega \hat{n}$.)
The terms $na^\dagger$ and $na$ describe creation and annihilation of particles, with the matrix element that is proportional to the occupation of the state. This is a rather generic Hamiltonian that may arise in many different context. E.g., such terms arise whenn describing Bose-Einstein condensation, when starting with a Hamiltonian
$$na^\dagger a_0 + na_0^\dagger a,$$
where $a_0,a_0^\dagger$ are the operators of the ground state mode, which can be replaced by a complex number due to their large occupation numbers (See AGD or Fetter&Walecka.)
Note that, if $n=a^\dagger a$, then the Hamiltonian in question is necessarily a boson Hamiltonian, since for Fermions $a^2=(a^\dagger)^2=0$, and we could reduce the Hamiltonian to a simpler form (which also brings to attention the fact that the Hamiltonian in question is not normal ordered, as is expected conventionally.)
